# what is the difference between rawurl and query string?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i read about httphandler and they  use rawurl and then they said :
For example, suppose you rewrote the HTTP handler that processes image requests so that
it is based on the query string instead of the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpRequest.RawUrl Property Gets the raw URL of the current request.

see more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl(v=vs.110).aspx

html addresses use QueryString property to pass values between pages

http://www.localhost.com/Webform2.aspx?name=Atilla&lastName=Ozgur

Webform2.aspx this is the page your browser will go.
name=Atilla you send a name variable which is set to Atilla
lastName=Ozgur you send a lastName variable which is set to Ozgur

Answer (score 2):

When you make a url rewrite the `Request.RawUrl` is shown the url that user see on the bar, there you do not have the query strings that you have rewrite.

For example if you rewrite the `www.site.com/2/product` to `www.site.com/product.aspx?id=2` to been able to read the `id` you need to use the Query string, because the `RawUrl` did not have it.